# List of exceptions in socket python

Tags: python, exception, tcpsocket

What are the exceptions which generates while using functions of socket lib in Python language. 
I have list of exception errors, but dont know which error are for socket function. https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html
I want to handle every error cases in TCP socket.

```
import socket
import sys
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('192.168.1.26', 56000)
while True:
    try:
        sock.connect(server_address)
        break
    except socket.error as e:
        print "error while connecting ::%s",e
while True:
    try:

        # Send data
        message = 'This is the message.  It will be repeated.'
        print >>sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message
        sock.sendall(message)
    except socket.error as e:
        print "error while sending ::%s",e
```

Comment: Socket errors are described in https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?#socket.error

Answer (score 5):

because you send many requests
and when you send many requests
the host will automatiquly block you
i will try to fix the repeat Error Exceptions with my own script:

```
import socket
import sys
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server = '192.168.1.26'
port = 56000
while True:
    try:
        s.connect((server, port))
    except socket.error as e:
        print "error while connecting :: %s" % e
        break
while True:
    try:
        # Send data
        message = 'This is the message.  It will be repeated.'
        print 'sending "%s"' % message
        s.send(message)
    except socket.error as e:
        print "error while sending :: " + str(e)
        break
```

thats it